# How to pick and export the deepest points of a DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, xyz, path

I am trying to work out how I can pick and export (to XYZ) the deepest path of a DEM.

I have a DEM surface (created from an 20cm XYZ file) where a straight line trench has been cut and I wish to pick the deepest part of this trench at a regular interval - say every 1m.

Rather than digitising a line myself is there a tool(s) within QGIS which can automate this process?

One method I have tried is by cutting cross profile every meter, from which I can determine the deepest value (bottom of trench), but what I can't work out is how to export just the deepest points from each CX to an XYZ file.

What I am trying to end up with is an XYZ file which correlates to the path of deepest position of the trench.